# java exception code error drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, debugging, drag-and-drop, jtable

There is an error in this code. The code should not rewrite the path of the file obtained by dragging if it already exists. Could you help me please? I'm implementing drag and drop. The original file

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Main extends JFrame implements DropTargetListener {

  DropTarget dt;


  JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();

  public Main() {
    super("Drop Test");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    add(new JLabel("Drop a list from your file chooser here:"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ta.setBackground(Color.white);
    getContentPane().add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    dt = new DropTarget(ta, this);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
//      System.out.println("Drag Enter");
  }

  public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
//      System.out.println("Source: " + dte.getSource());
//      System.out.println("Drag Exit");
  }

  public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
//      System.out.println("Drag Over");
  }

  public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
//      System.out.println("Drop Action Changed");
  }


public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
      try {
          Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
          DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
          for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Possible flavor: " + flavors[i].getMimeType());
            if (flavors[i].isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
              dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);

             // ta.setText("Successful file list drop.\n\n");

              //System.out.println("---"+ta.getText());
              java.util.List list = (java.util.List) tr.getTransferData(flavors[i]);
              for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                  StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ta.getText(), "\n");
                  ta.append(list.get(j) + "\n");

              }

            }

              dtde.dropComplete(true);
              return;

          }
          System.out.println("Drop failed: " + dtde);
          dtde.rejectDrop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          dtde.rejectDrop();
        }
      }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main();
  }
}
```

Comment: please include the error message or stacktrace.

Comment: also: don't use deprecated material. StringTokenizer has been deprecated for several versions of Java.
As for your code, we don't know what's in your list (both type and contents) so won't make any guesses about that

Comment: The mistake is that if I copy the same files by dragging it rewrites all times and this should not happen. I wish if the file exists, insert the latest version of the file

Comment: There are many problems with this code. It starts with variable names that don't follow java coding styles; then it uses == to compare strings (should be equals), and so on.

Comment: @Jägermeister in java 8 you can check equality between two strings with ==

Comment: @pinokio you could always do that, but it compares references, not the values

Comment: I modified this is the original file without handle exceptions

Comment: @pinokio Yes, with java 8, == might give the same results as equals(). But that really depends on the situation; and still; that is definitely not something that you ever want to mention around newbies.

Comment: ok so someone can help me with my problem?

Comment: *"someone can help me with my problem?"* Please describe the current behavior in detail, and how it is not what is required.

Comment: This is a prototype of an e-mail manager. What I want is for drag insert attachments (this already does). What I want is that if that attachment exists should not be copied but rewritten!

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`Transferable#getTransderData(DataFlavor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html#getTransferData-java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor-)

Answer (score 1):

This is where a single exit point to a method would have helped you...

Let's strip out some code and have a closer look...

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    try {
        Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
        for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Possible flavor: " + flavors[i].getMimeType());
            if (flavors[i].isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                //...
            }
            // !!!
            dtde.dropComplete(true);
            return;
            // !!!
        }
        System.out.println("Drop failed: " + dtde);
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}
```

Basically, when you're looping through all the available `DataFlavors`, you immediately accept the drop and `return` on the first one.

So, if instead, we move those lines to within the `if` statement

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    try {
        Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
        DataFlavor[] flavors = tr.getTransferDataFlavors();
        for (int i = 0; i < flavors.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Possible flavor: " + flavors[i].getMimeType());
            if (flavors[i].isFlavorJavaFileListType()) {
                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);

                // ta.setText("Successful file list drop.\n\n");
                //System.out.println("---"+ta.getText());
                java.util.List list = (java.util.List) tr.getTransferData(flavors[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(ta.getText(), "\n");
                    ta.append(list.get(j) + "\n");

                }
                dtde.dropComplete(true);
                return;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Drop failed: " + dtde);
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}
```

it will start working.

We could, however, simplify the code a little by making better use of the available functionality, for example...

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    try {
        Transferable tr = dtde.getTransferable();
        if (tr.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
            dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
            List files = (List) tr.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
            for (Object obj : files) {
                ta.append(obj + "\n");
            }
            dtde.dropComplete(true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Drop failed: " + dtde);
            dtde.rejectDrop();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        dtde.rejectDrop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem has not been resolved .
Within the textArea must not be displayed eg duplicate the same file. I'm thinking of creating a temporary file but do not know if it is a good idea

Comment: I'm trying to use this technique. But it does not work at all. Could you fix it please?
[Code]
         //java.util.List list = (java.util.List) tr.getTransferData(flavors[i]);
            List list = (List) tr.getTransferData(flavors[i]);

          for (Object item : list) {
              File file = (File) item;
              if(file.exists())
               file.delete();
              else
               ta.append( file + "\n");
              
             
          }

Comment: *"Thanks for the answer but the problem has not been resolved "* - Wait, back up, the problem was the drag'n'drop wasn't working, which now works. Duplicate files can easily be using a `Set`

Comment: `if(file.exists()) file.delete();` ... well, since the user dragged files in from the OS, this will always be `true` and you will end up deleting the file from the disk